# how to load data in the datalist

Tags: java, jsf

I have a database named ball, and it has and ID and a name.

I generated the entity and jsf pages using CRUD

by adding

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="btable" value="#{ballController.items}" var="item">
         <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.bname}"/>
         </h:column>
    </h:dataTable> 
</h:form>
```

to my page it displays the list of the datas in the database, id and name.

i tried debugging the generated code and ballController.items calls:

```
public DataModel getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    return items;
}
```

to generate the datas in the datatable.

but there is no method to reload the datas.

i tried creating a button

```
<h:commandButton action="#{ballCOntroller.getItems}" value="test">
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render="btable" />
</h:commandButton>
```

to execute getItems, in a test to reload the datatable but it does not work.

i'm sure i need to create another method to do this but i'm not sure where to start. do i need to query the database and return a list? to generate the datatable?

*EDIT

controller:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ballController")
@ViewScoped
public class ballController implements Serializable {

    private ball current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB
    private ballFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;

    public ballController() {
    }

    public ball getSelected() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = new ball();
            selectedItemIndex = -1;
        }
        return current;
    }

    private ballFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
        if (pagination == null) {
            pagination = new PaginationHelper(10) {
                @Override
                public int getItemsCount() {
                    return getFacade().count();
                }

                @Override
                public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                    return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
                }
            };
        }
        return pagination;
    }

    public String prepareList() {
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String prepareView() {
        current = (ball) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "View";
    }

    public String prepareCreate() {
        current = new ball();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
        return "index";
    }

    public String create() {
        try {

            getFacade().create(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ballCreated"));
            return prepareCreate();
//            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String prepareEdit() {
        current = (ball) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "Edit";
    }

    public String update() {
        try {
            getFacade().edit(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ballUpdated"));
            return "View";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String destroy() {
        current = (ball) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        performDestroy();
        recreatePagination();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String destroyAndView() {
        performDestroy();
        recreateModel();
        updateCurrentItem();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            return "View";
        } else {
            // all items were removed - go back to list
            recreateModel();
            return "List";
        }
    }

    private void performDestroy() {
        try {
            getFacade().remove(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ballDeleted"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    private void updateCurrentItem() {
        int count = getFacade().count();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= count) {
            // selected index cannot be bigger than number of items:
            selectedItemIndex = count - 1;
            // go to previous page if last page disappeared:
            if (pagination.getPageFirstItem() >= count) {
                pagination.previousPage();
            }
        }
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            current = getFacade().findRange(new int[]{selectedItemIndex, selectedItemIndex + 1}).get(0);
        }
    }

    public DataModel getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
        }
        return items;

    }

    private void recreateModel() {
        items = null;
    }

    private void recreatePagination() {
        pagination = null;
    }

    public String next() {
        getPagination().nextPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String previous() {
        getPagination().previousPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), false);
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), true);
    }

    @FacesConverter(forClass = ball.class)
    public static class ballControllerConverter implements Converter {

        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            ballController controller = (ballController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "ballController");
            return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
        }

        java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
            java.lang.Integer key;
            key = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return key;
        }

        String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(value);
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof ball) {
                ball o = (ball) object;
                return getStringKey(o.getId());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + ball.class.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the following way works for you?

**JSF Page**

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="btable" value="#{ballController.items}" var="item">
         <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
         </h:column>
         <h:column>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.bname}"/>
         </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton action="#{ballController.retrieveItems}" value="Reload">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="btable" />
    </h:commandButton> 
</h:form>
```

**Controller**

```
private DataModel items;
//Getter and Setter Methods

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
}

public void retrieveItems() {
    items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
}
```

Comment: hi, i get this error `serverError: class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0` after pressing the reload button

Comment: @RowiePo have you debugged where arises this problem: in the `getPagination` or `createPageDataModel` function? This is indeed an answer to the problem stated in the question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i also have a create function, i noticed that after i create a ball and insert it to the database, when i press the reload function that error pops up, but if i go to the database directly and manually delete or add data, the reload function works fine. i will update the question and add the create function for you to check

Comment: btw, the error does not display on my Glash Fish server, it pops out like a jquery alert

Comment: @RowiePo Pls double check your saving functions. I think the above way should works for data reloading.

Comment: the saving function is also auto generated by CRUD, i cant seem to find any problem on the saving function coz it work just fine. i'm confused why i'm having index out of bounds. i will update the whole code for my controller in the main question

Comment: i tried debugging the retrieveItems() but the error already occurs before invoking the method